# Compare date of productstock not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, date

I currently use the following code, to check if the `$productEta` is in the future, based on the date of today. But that is not working well.

Its a dynamic code, so I will provide the entire code:

```
$productEta = '01-07-2019';
date("m-d-Y") = '12-28-2018';

<?php if ($productEta < date("m-d-Y")) :?>
TEST
<?php endif; ?>
```

But today it is showing TEST, but that should not be right. Because the `$productEta` value is larger than the current date. So it should skip it. The year seems to be the problem, that it does not check 2018 or 2019.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't even look like php. No quotes, no semicolons, the way to use the date() function ... you should have a lot of errors in your error_log, haven't you?

Comment: @digijay No, because it is in Magento, so a lot of the code is already there.

Comment: Umm, I know Magento quite well, from ver. 1.6 to 2.2 ... but I have never seen code like this. IMHO it shouldn't work at all. **ahh, you just edited it!** `$productEta` contains a string, how would you compare that to a date? Have a look at `strtotime()`

Comment: @digijay Yes, already tried this: `if (strtotime($productEta) < time())` but in that case the same result. It still does not check if the $productEta is in the past.